# Radical of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, bilinear-form

Given a bilinear form $b$ on a vector space, one defines the *radical*, which is the set of vectors which are orthogonal (with respect to $b$) to every other vector (so essentially the orthogonal complement of the whole space). My question is: Why is it called radical? Is there an example that motivates this name?

Comment: I have never heard this term in this context. Is it connected to the concept of isotropic cone as for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2682566/305862) ?

Comment: I am not sure!…

Comment: @JeanMarie  Hi!   I put an answer with excerpts from Witt(1936)  and from Serre's little book, the 1970 French original,  English translation  was about 1973

Comment: @WillJagy I’m sorry for my ignorance, I still don’t quite get why it’s called “radical”

Answer (score -1):

This goes back, at least, to Witt(1936)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Now, I understand. Thanks. How clear and modern is the style of Witt ! When you read the text of Serre there is hardly any difference of style... How influential has been the german school of 1880-1930 !